# Как добавить меню в разметку XML

Tags: android, xml

Имею такую разметку:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <AutoCompleteTextView
        android:id="@+id/autoCompleteTextView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text=""
        android:hint="Найти собеседника...">
        <requestFocus />
    </AutoCompleteTextView>

    <ListView
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        tools:listitem="@android:layout/simple_list_item_2" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Нашёл в сети пример, но не понимаю куда его вставить? Куда бы я не вставлял всегда пишет ошибки в разметке.

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  tools:context=".MainActivity">

   <item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"
        app:showAsAction="never"/>
</menu>
```

Comment: у вас и есть ошибка в разметке - во втором примере у вас тег <menu> не закрыт - нет закрытия тега, </menu>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ну вообще, разметка меню, видимо, из примера про меню actionbar'а. Ее не надо вставлять в разметку активити. она добавляется программно:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu); //здесь указываешь на файл разметки меню
    return true;
}

//обработка нажатия
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {     
    switch(item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_settings:
        //add the function to perform here
        return(true);
    }
    return(super.onOptionsItemSelected(item));
}
```